# Netbeans useful keyboard shortcuts

Tags: java, netbeans

Could anyone write or give a link to useful keyboard shortcuts in NetBeans? I use this IDE and I would like to know useful things, when creating any application in java.

I ask for more than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, but I ask for keyboard shortcuts especially in Java.

On the Internet I found a lot of keyboard shortcuts, but I cannot find site with useful ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be the following PDF: https://usersguide.netbeans.org/shortcuts.pdf

Note that it is written for Netbeans 7.4, so depending on your version, not everything needs to be in use.

Also this topic is worth the read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628830/netbeans-tips-and-tricks?rq=1

Comment: +1 seems to be just exactly what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can check and change these in the Settings.

`Tools -> Options -> Keymap`

Cool is e.g. auto-format.

What is useful and what not is very dependent on your coding-stlye, teamwork etc. Also the actual shortcut can be configured, so it can be different on any computer.

---

You can also create shortcuts like type `sysout` and then press Clt+Space.

You find and can edit/add these here `Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates`